# How to convert one json layout to different layout

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, graphql

Do we have any tools or technologies where I can pass a layout as input and get layout in different format based on my requirement. I have one REST end point and it is being used by 2 different user and in future there will be multiple users.

First user wants response in below format.
layout1:

```
{
  user2: "user1",   
  eligibileCount:"5",
  business:"FI",
  metalLevel:"Gold",
  productType:"Balanced",
  planCode:"GDFT",
  planType:"INS",
  nationalAccess:"No",
  metalTier:"Gold",
  licenseType:"INS"
  pcpRequired:"Y",
  packageInd:"K8472"
}
```

Second user wants response in below format. This layout will be complex but I am using a simple example.
layout2:

```
{
  user2: "user2",
  eligibileCount: "5",
  business: "FI",
  productType: "Balanced",
  nationalAccess: "No",
  licenseType: "INS"
  pcpRequired: "Y",
  packageIndicator: "test"
  metalInfo: {
    level: "Gold",
    tier: "Gold"
  }
  planInfo: {
    code: "sdkj",
    type: "cv"
  }
}
```

I am able to resolve this issue using java and spring boot but it required coding effort once a new user comes and wants a new layout.

Comment: This should be achievable via GraphQL with fields duplicated across the domain model.

Comment: How are your users expected to specify wanted layout?